# Submenu not replicating stylization in WordPress dropdown menu

Tags: php, css, wordpress, menu, dropdown

We set up a template for Wordpress.

However the submenus that require the dropdown to appear by: Hover are not working normally. They remain there already statically exposed under their menu item.

We did the styling of this specific submenu item and it went all normal.

Remebering that every new item has a new class, ex.: "item-02", "item-03" ...

However if another new submenu is needed, we will have to do the styling again individually.

Where should I work on the code, to configure that every new submenu item should have that styling and positioning already done?

I think it's not just a CSS issue, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

This is CSS. You should set the css in your styles.css file